# Implicitly unwrapped optional made immutable

Tags: swift

Why is it that I cannot mutate an implicitly unwrapped optional variable?

Here is a short example the reproduces the issue:

## With Array

```
var list: [Int]! = [1]
list.append(10) // Error here
```

`Immutable value of type '[Int]' only has mutating members named 'append'`

## With Int

```
var number: Int! = 1
number = 2
number = 2 + number
number += 2 // Error here
```

`Could not find an overload for '+=' that accepts the supplied arguments`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

This has been fixed in Xcode Beta 5 with one small caveat:

```
var list: [Int]! = [1]
list.append(10)

var number: Int! = 1
number! += 2
number += 2 // compile error
```

The array works as expected, but it seems that right now the integer still requires an explicit unwrap to allow using `+=`

---

Currently, this is just the nature of Optionals (whether implicitly unwrapped or not). The unwrap operator returns an immutable value. [This is likely to be fixed or a better solution will be provided in the future](https://devforums.apple.com/message/998882#998882).

The only way around it for now is to wrap the array in a class:

```
class IntArray {
    var elements : [Int]
}
```

Comment: The unwrap operator returns an immutable value because that's the nature of an immutable operation. As Lattner says there's isn't an obvious solution. Making the unwrap operation mutable is not a solution: you would not be able to use it on an immutable `Optional` and it would not solve the problem because the returned value would still be immutable (as all value types are always immutable).

Answer (score 5):

Because the way you are trying to mutate them is by mutating the values (which are immutable) instead of mutating the `var`.

In Swift value types are immutable. All and always.

Mutation is not a mutation of the value, it's a mutation of the variable that contains the value.

In the case of the `Int`, the `+=` operator gets a structure on the left and an Int on the right, and it cannot add a structure to an int.

In the case of the `Array` the `append` is a mutating member. But it's being invoked on an immutable value that is not directly stored in a variable. It can only operate on values that are directly stored in a variable (which is what makes them mutable: the fact that they are stored in a variable. They are not really mutable, the variable is).

Comment: Wrong. In Swift, value types like `String` and collection types like `Int[]` are **mutable by default, when assigning to a variable**. Only when you assign them to a constant (i.e. `let`), they become immutable. Please [refer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/StringsAndCharacters.html) to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/CollectionTypes.html).

Comment: It's the variable that is mutable, not the value. The value, for value types, is always immutable. The documentation sometimes speaks in a non formal way, other times is more formal. When it says that a string or an array is mutable when assigned to a `var` and immutable when assigned to a `let` it's just saying that the value itself is immutable, but you can assign it to a mutable `var` and mutate the var. That is why you cannot call a mutating method of anything that is just the argument of the constructor of another type.

Comment: `"If you create an array or a dictionary and assign it to a variable, the collection that is created will be mutable."` I don't see how this is unclear.

Comment: It is not unclear. It just does not mean what you think it means. It means that you can call mutating methods of that value. And what mutating methods do is they take a hidden argument that is the address of the variable, create A NEW value, and assign it to the variable. They do not mutate the actual original value (unless the compiler can prove that there was no aliasing or sharing, in which case it can perform optimizations and actually mutate the original storage, but this happens transparently).

Comment: Note in particular that, for Arrays, mutation of the array means mutation of the length but not mutation of the content. And in fact this is why the `append` call failed in the OP: it is a mutating method of the array. It needs to create a new array and assign it to a variable, but it can only do it if it has a variable, and there was no variable containing the array.

Comment: value types are not always immutable, that is why there are [mutable members](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_305). Instead it is this specific circumstance that the unwrap operator on Optionals returns an immutable value.

Comment: @drewag Value types are immutable. Mutable members do not really mutate a value, they compute a completely new value. That's why they can only be invoked on a `var`: they silently take a reference to the `var` so that they can 'assign' the newly computed value to it.

Comment: @AnalogFile The low level mutation implementation is not significant. At the language level, value types can be both mutable and immutable which is why the error reads "Immutable value of type 'Int[]' only has mutating members named 'append'" How can a value type have mutating members if a value type can not be considered to be mutable? Your explanation may be the reason that it is hard for them to implement mutation on optionals, but ultimately they are planning to make it possible to mutate an optional like I want. Saying that value types are never mutable, confuses the issue in my opinion

Comment: @AnalogFile, Also the documentation says this about mutating methods: `The method can then mutate (that is, change) its properties from within the method, and any changes that it makes are written back to the original structure when the method ends`

Comment: @drewag A value type is not mutable. It can have a mutating member exactly because _mutating_ does not mean it mutates the value, it means it mutates a reference to a value of that type. This does not confuses the issue. It makes it clearer. It only seems confusing if you do not understand what _value_ means. Study some abstract mathematics and/or a language like Haskell and it becomes extremely clear.

Comment: As for the documentation I do feel that Apple documentation is often misleading because it tries to cater for people that are not used to the precise abstractions underlying the semantics of whatever the documentation is about. Building intuitive understanding is good, but intuitive understanding is always misleading. It shall be a step stone in the path to a more abstract and correct understanding. People should build on their own intuition, not be given a pre-cooked one. Otherwise they'll be trapped for a long time in the delusion of thinking the intuition is the abstraction, while it's not.

Comment: @AnalogFile FYI, Apple has now made them mutable in Xcode 6 beta 5