# Immutable value of type 'Any[]' only has mutating members named 'append' in Swift, despite the array is defined as 'var'

Tags: ios, swift

I want to append a new object to my Array, which is defined as `var` in my Swift app, but despite me defining it as `var`, the following error occurred when I tried to append it.

```
`Immutable value of type 'Any[]' only has mutating members named 'append'`
```

Here's my code:

```
var contactsArray: Any[]!
func popoverWillClose(notification: NSNotification) {
    if popoverTxtName.stringValue != "" && popoverTxtContactInfo.stringValue != "" {
        contactsArray.append(makeDictionaryRecord(popoverTxtName.stringValue, withInfo: popoverTxtContactInfo.stringValue))
    }
}
```

(`makeDictionaryRecord(withInfo:)` method takes two `String` and returns `Dictionary<String, Any>`)

My original code defines `contactsArray` as `let`, and later I found it was my mistake, so I changed it to `var`. However, things still didn't make it so far.

I also changed the type of components of `contactsArray` to `AnyObject[]`, `Any[]`, and `AnyObject[]!`, but nothing didn't change at all.

( That being said, since the `contactsArray` has to take `Dictionary` within it, it has to be defined as either `Any[]` or `Any[]!`, since `Dictionary` is defined as struct, if I understand it correctly. )

What's wrong with my code? How can I properly append the component to `contactsArray`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implicitly unwrapped optional made immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091729/implicitly-unwrapped-optional-made-immutable)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>Problem 1: You've defined `contactsArray` as an implicitly unwrapped Optional, but the values of Optional variables are always immutable. You can define it this way instead to allow appending values:</strike>

```
var contactsArray: [Any]
```

*Update:* This hasn't been a problem since Swift introduced assignment through optional chaining. With implicitly unwrapped optionals, this happens automatically.

Problem 2: You haven't given the array an initial value -- <strike>the compiler starts complaining about *that* when you fix problem 1</strike> for an implicitly unwrapped optional, that means the value is `nil`, so you'll get a runtime exception. The solution is to initialize the variable with an empty array:

```
var contactsArray: [Any]! = []
```

You *almost never* need an optional Array—an empty array is just as good a signifier of "no values" as `nil`, and safer, to boot. If you decide to use an optional array anyway, use a regular optional (i.e., declared with `?`), not an implicitly unwrapped one:

```
var contactsArray: [Any]? = []
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that the optional is always immutable. However, is it still possible to define an array as both optional and mutable? I might want to assign `nil` during the lifetime of the application...

Comment: Nope! I'd stick with empty arrays instead of `nil`. If you absolutely need optionality (?) you'll have to make variable, non-optional copy of the array, add to it, then reassign to `self.contactsArray`.

Answer (score 11):

The syntax for array declaration has been changed, it's now

`var contractsArray: [Any] = []`

Also if you're modifying an array as part of a struct or an enum you might see this error. A struct or an enum is a value type and the method needs the `mutating` keyword:

```
struct contacts {
    var contactsArray:[Any] = []
    mutating func popoverWillClose(notification: NSNotification) {
        if popoverTxtName.stringValue != "" && popoverTxtContactInfo.stringValue != "" {

            contactsArray.append(makeDictionaryRecord(popoverTxtName.stringValue, withInfo: popoverTxtContactInfo.stringValue))
        }
    }
}
```

In addition you cannot save instances of a struct with mutating methods as a constant using the `let` keyword, it needs to be declared as `var` because the value for the variable will change when you call a mutating function.